# Wrong offset in DW_OP_fbreg DWARF

Tags: c, linux, vscode-debugger

I used DWARF and I did the command:

```
objdump --dwarf=info check
```

And the interesting DIE of the specific variable I search:

```
<2><c5>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_variable)

<c6>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xac): index

<ca>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1

<ca>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 19

<cb>   DW_AT_decl_column : 9

<cc>   DW_AT_type        : <0x58>

<d0>   DW_AT_location    : 3 byte block: 91 b0 7f   (DW_OP_fbreg: -80)
```

I am working with a 64-bit system so I understand that the offset is from frame base - rsp.

I printed in runtime the values of registers rsp, rbp, and index variable memory address (with &index).

And got:

**index address: 0x7fff83abad10**

**rsp: 0x7fff83abad10**

**rbp: 0x7fff83abad50**

I also used to clarify with gdb:

**print from index address: 0x7fffffffdfd0**

**RBP: 0x7fffffffe010**

**RSP: 0x7fffffffdfd0**

**So my question is how it makes sense that the memory address of the index variable is the same as the rsp register** in two checks (running program and gdb) while from DIE I got the output:

**DW_AT_location    : 3 byte block: 91 b0 7f     (DW_OP_fbreg: -80)**

it's supposed to be that the address of index variable + 80 = rsp?